# Should I overcharge mobile phone before first using?

Tags: battery-life, mobile-phone

When I first buy a mobile phone or phone battery I used to know i should charge it about 8-10 hrs switched off the phone.

But i don't know if its actually necessary to overcharge a battery for its longevity.

So should i overcharge my new mobile phone or just charge it until it get fully charged. FYI: my battery is Lithium Ion Battery.

Comment: This shouldn't be necessary anymore with the newer batteries - in fact you can begin using it straight away for that matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the battery is first put on charge, the voltage shoots up quickly. This behavior can be compared to lifting a heavy weight with an elastic band. The lifting arm moves up quickly but the weight lags behind. The voltage of the charging battery will only catch up when the battery is almost fully charged.

Li-ion cannot absorb overcharge, and when fully charged the charge current must be cut off. A continuous trickle charge would cause plating of metallic lithium, and this could compromise safety.

Source [Battery University](http://batteryuniversity.com/learn/article/charging_lithium_ion_batteries)

Comment: so, it should not overcharged right? And should i switched off the mobile before charging?

Comment: Depending on your phone, your phone may see that the battery is fully charged and revert the current from charging to maintaining power. I would say that you do not need to turn off your phone. I would check with either the retail store or manufacture.